# javascript search string contains ' + '

Tags: javascript, regex, search

i would to search a string into another string but i'm facing an issue.

There is my code :

```
reference = "project/+bug/1234";
str = "+bug/1234";
alert(reference.search(str));
//it should alert 8 (index of matched strings)
```

but it alert -1 : so, str wasn't found into reference.

I've found what's the problem is, and it seems to be the " + " character into str, because .search("string+str") seems to evaluate searched string with the regex " + "

Comment: Rather than using reference.search(str);
use reference.indexOf(str);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`string.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf). It takes a literal string instead of converting the string to a RegExp object (like [`string.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) does):

```
> reference = "project/+bug/1234";
> str = "+bug/1234";
> console.log(reference.indexOf(str));
8
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the explaination ! It's work fine now !!
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
reference = "project/+bug/1234";
str = "+bug/1234";
alert(reference.indexOf("+bug/1234"));
```