# JS if window.location.href contains specific combination

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to check that window.location.href contains something like this `,c4353,p8547` for ex. `https://example.com/asdasd-dsadsa,c7456,p4354,en.html`. Numbers after `c` and `p` are random.

Comment: How is jQuery related to this? Looks like a simple regex would do. Have you tried one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript search string contains ' + '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17363955/javascript-search-string-contains)

Comment: i tried `if(window.location.href.indexOf("c[0-9]\,p[0-9]") > -1)` and many others combinations but it doesn't work

Comment: That’s not a regex, and `indexOf` doesn’t take RegExps. Try [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the comments above, you could test it with `Regex.test` function:

```
var href = window.location.href;

// returns true if pattern is found
var containsPattern = /c[0-9]*\,p[0-9]*/g.test(href);

if(containsPattern) {
    ...
}
```

If you need to get the values matched, you should use the `string.match` function:

```
var href = window.location.href;

// returns an array with all the strings that matches your regex
var matches = href.match(/c[0-9]*\,p[0-9]*/g);
```

Then you could extract the numbers or whatever you want with this